# How to tell when GA4 data is finalised from the API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I download data on a daily basis from the GA4 API to provide a report on our website for the previous day to management. There's a strong business reason for this to be as timely as possible.

However it seems difficult to detect ***when*** to run the report. If it's run too early, the data won't be complete and is often more unhelpful than helpful. The best indicator we've come up with so far is when the event data is exported to our BigQuery dataset - this certainly seems to be after the data from the API has stabilised , but from reading around it's possible that this export can happen some time after the API data is OK.

From tests we've run, the time at which the data from the API settles can vary by a couple of hours so we can't simply download data at (say) 11am. Is there any way of getting a better indicator of when the data is ready - an API query for example? I am aware that the data can be amended for several days but this is typically trivial changes.